# wpf default comboBox item when data-binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I was following the tutorial [Binding a comboBox to an Enum](http://jacobmsaylor.com/?p=908) 
and came out with this XML code:

```
    <ComboBox 
        DisplayMemberPath="Key"
        SelectedValuePath="Value"
        ItemsSource="{Binding VolumeLevelList}"
        SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedVolumeLevel, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, Mode=TwoWay}"
        Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="189,70,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
```

I'm looking for a way to select a default choice, something like

> SelectedIndex="0"

But thats not working..

Comment: How are you exactly setting the index to 0? In the code behind?

Comment: @programmer93 No, just as an attribue in the comboBox XML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downloaded the code from tutorial and noticed that something is missing. In the `MainViewModel`, `INotifyPropertyChanged` is correctly implemented, however, the `SelectedVolumeLevel` property doesn't call the `RaisePropertyChanged()` method on `set`. What this means is that when you update the combobox, the source doesn't get updated. The reason your `SelectedIndex` doesn't work is because the `SelectedValue` is already set and bound to the source. To fix this, add a backing field to your `MainViewModel` like this:

```
private VolumeLevel selectedVolumeLevel = VolumeLevel.LowVolume; // Default is set to low
```

Then change the `SelectedVolumeLevel` property to this:

```
public VolumeLevel SelectedVolumeLevel
{
    get { return selectedVolumeLevel; }
    set { selectedVolumeLevel = value; RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedVolumeLevel"); }
}
```

Now every time the selected item in the combobox is changed, the source properly gets updated. This should also fix your default choice issue.

Comment: My apologies about the unfinished code. The example project has been updated for anybody navigating to the site in the future.